# Iterate through JSON array with either a for-each loop or by using an Iterator (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I'm currently trying to iterate through a JSONArray with either a for-each loop or an Iterator instead of a normal for-loop, but looks like org.json doesn't support them. Any ideas how to edit the following code so that it can work, I've been trying for like 4 hours to find a soluton but sadly without any success. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the important part of the code:

```
String strJson = loadJsonFromAssetsFolder();
JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("restaurant");
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            list.add(jsonObject.optString("name").toString());
  }
```

A little clarification. The first line basically is the text in the jsonFile represented as a String. At first I added the values to a simple array of Strings, but then I changed it to an ArrayList, since it would be logical if I were to use the for-each loop. I tried using org.json.simple, net.sf.json as an alternative but I couldn't do it with neither of those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iterator, as JsonArray provides a getIterator method. However these are raw iterators, so there is no specific type associated with them (so every element is considered to be an Object). You can downcast them though.

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String strJson = loadJsonFromAssetsFolder();
    JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(strJson);
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("restaurant");
    for (Object jsonObject : jsonArray) {
        list.add(((JSONObject) jsonObject).optString("name"));
    }
```

Is there any reason why you don't want to use a normal for loop? There is no difference really. 
 You could also look into libraries like GSON, which can map it to a Java Object.

Comment: Well, the thing is that it works perfectly fine (from my point of view) with a normal for loop, but one of my team mates (for this project that we're working on) who reviewed my code (and has much more exp than me) told me that it would be better if I accessed an element of the array by using the foreach loop, since the normal one could "unnecessarily traverse the whole array" if, for example, I wanted to access the last element in the last iteration of the loop. 
Btw, I tried your suggestion already, but it didn't work, foreach is somehow not possible for org.json. And thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Metodi What do you mean it didn't work? The code above runs perfectly fine. I don't get the argument from your team mate. The iteration is the very same, the only difference is that you'll lose the index variable and the array length is only calculated once, which you can also do manually.

Comment: When I use the foreach loop I get an error message saying "foreach not applicable to type org.json.JSONArray". That would work if I used a different library but that would mean I need to change almost everything which would be extremely annoying given the fact that I've already tried it. I'm gonna wait for his answer as well, since I also thought that foreach is equivalent to the for loop, just makes the code shorter by getting rid of the index.

Comment: @Metodi That's weird. for (Object jsonObject : jsonArray) works for me with org.json versions of 2016 and 2017. Which version are you using?

Comment: Hmmm, where can I check that? That may be the case, if Android Studio has a built-in older version of org.json and I need to update it.

Comment: @Metodi Just checked, google did indeed reimplement the org.json version, so it has a different API (for example, doesnt feature the iterator method, so foreach can't work).