# foreach not applicable to type org.json.jsonArray

Tags: java

Same question was asked on the below link.
[Why for each loop is not applicable for JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35771392/8584761)
Can we import any jar so that it would work?

Comment: No, that's not how Java works I'm afraid.

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479032/iterate-through-json-array-with-either-a-for-each-loop-or-by-using-an-iterator>

Comment: You asked if it's possible to import a JAR which would make an object usable in a foreach loop where it wasn't before.  The answer to that question is no.  If you want to follow up on someone else's answer, you should do it there, not in the form of a new question.

Comment: Then spend a bit of time on the site, earn a bit of reputation, and then you can comment.  Questions like this are of a low quality and do not belong here.

Comment: @JoeC:  Actually...if you have a follow-up question to someone's earlier question, posting your *own* question is the absolute right course of action.  The answer may still be "no", but that doesn't mean that the OP is doing the wrong thing on the site.

Comment: @JoeC, you are right. But low quality question is for you.. but not for me..Anyway thanks for your comments / time.

Answer (score 4):

Java "foreach" syntax is not applicable because the `JSONArray` API does not implement the `Iterable` interface.

> Can we import any jar so that it would work?

The answer to that is No.  The `org.json` APIs are "baked in" for Android.  I don't think they can be changed without modifying / replacing the Android runtime libraries.

The solution is to either petition "someone"<sup>1</sup> to change the official `org.json` APIs in Android.

Or use a different JSON API, which could be problematic depending on the other APIs that you are using.

Or just bite the bullet and use indexing.  It is not *that* bad ...

---

<sup>1 - Good luck with that!  For a start, it is not clear *who* you should petition ...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

JSONArray is only iterable starting from [JSON-java 20150729](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/releases/tag/20150729). You need to update your version.